# Visualising a subset of the tree of life

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics

I understand that many curated trees of life already exist (eg http://tolweb.org/tree/) but is there any website that allows one to input a list of organisms, and then produce the current best guess at their evolutionary relationships?

The best site I managed to find so far is http://itol.embl.de/itol.cgi, which allows you to select specific species from the main tree to plot into a sub-tree, but the tree itself is rather small, so more detailed comparisons cannot be made.

Comment: So you mean a site that can produce a phylogenetic tree for a group of chosen species, based on an underlying database of phylogenetic relationships?

Comment: @fileunderwater Yes, that would work.

Comment: I have a similar project, this option you need could be added in the future. Take a look: http://dao.url.ph/tree/tree.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://phylot.biobyte.de/ performs the requisite task (generating a phylogenetic tree based on the specific organisms provided, using the NCBI taxonomy tables).

For example, the input of tree elements

> Trichomonas vaginalis,Trypanosoma brucei,Homo sapiens,Fibroporia
>   radiculosa,Paramecium tetraurelia,Tetrahymena
>   thermophila,Cryptosporidium muris,Cryptosporidium hominis,Blastocystis
>   hominis

generates the tree

[image]

Comment: Really cool resource!