# How do I generate a phylometric tree given species names?

Tags: phylogenetics

I have a list of species. I want to put those names into a tool and get back a visualized tree that includes names of shared order, suborder, family and genus.
Is there an existing tool that does this job for me or do I need to program my own solution?

(The solutuion in the [other thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28500/visualising-a-subset-of-the-tree-of-life) only shows the name of the species but not order/suborder/family/genus)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visualising a subset of the tree of life](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/28500/visualising-a-subset-of-the-tree-of-life)

Answer (score 2):

Biopython may have a module for this. I know it can parses phyloxml files and render a tree. You can query the ncbi database for the xml files. Here is some sample code that will render an ascii tree given a phyloxml file...

```
from Bio import Phylo
tree = Phylo.read("examplephylo.xml", "phyloxml")
Phylo.drawascii(tree)
```

There is also support for drawing more graphically rich trees using matplotlib. There is a .pdf book for Biopython that you can download from this url http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.pdf

Hope that helps

Comment: There is support for other file types besides phyloxml, but I can only speak for the phyloxml files, because I have used them personally.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there isn't an easy one-stop-shop solution for what you'd like to do.

My own solution for doing something similar (with the caveat that the NCBI taxonomies are not always up-to-date with the latest data) is to a) use [NCBI's Common Tree](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/CommonTree/wwwcmt.cgi) page to build out the lineages you'd like to include and download it as a text tree (e.g. in Phylip format, which includes internal nodes), b) visualize the tree on a local computer using something like [TreeView X](https://code.google.com/p/treeviewx/) or [FigTree](http://tree.bio.ed.ac.uk/software/figtree/)

It's a bit of a pain, but if you'd like to add additional metadata to the tree before visualizing it, you can edit the Phylip-formatted text file directly before opening it in one of the viewers.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily doable in the R package 'rotl' with only three simple commands.

E.g.

```
library(rotl)
taxa<-tnrs_match_names(names= c("Danaus plexippus",
                       "Sylvia atricapilla",
                       "Acrocephalus arundinaceus",
                       "Anas platyrhynchos",
                       "Oncorhynchus nerka",
                       "Hirundo pyrrhonota",
                       "Progne subis"))

tree <- tol_induced_subtree(ott_ids = ott_id(taxa))

plot(tree, cex = .8, label.offset = .1, no.margin = TRUE)
```

Full details outlined here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12593/full